# VS2010 beta 1 Intellisense Speed

Tags: visual-studio-2010, intellisense

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Beta 1. Intellisense is SO SLOW. There's a good half a second delay after I press any key in the source code window. This is absolutely crippling to my development speed. Is there anything I can do to speed up Intellisense? I lost my Visual Studio 2008 key :(.

Comment: 1) You don't mention which language you're using.
2) It's a beta. Lot of things aren't optimized yet.

Comment: You think the language really matters? It's C#. Just wondering if anyone has any hacks or workarounds.

Comment: Yes, the language matters. It's the language that provides the intellisense!

Comment: Are you in a VM? Can make a big difference.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use an [express version](http://www.microsoft.com/express/) (rather than a beta edition since you lost your key)?  They are free and very zippy, but don't support some of the essentials like ReSharper.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the beta man.  You're better off using [the express ed](http://www.microsoft.com/express/vcsharp/) of 2k8.

Answer (score 1):

Like was mentioned in the comments, the language matters. Nevertheless, I bet the following (do all of them) get you moving again. I plan to go back to my preferred settings with Beta 2 and see if things have improved.

- Set your Windows appearance to Windows Classic. I don't like it either. Do it.
- Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Advanced > Uncheck "Highlight references to symbol under cursor". Additional note: I've confirmed with the C# IDE team that this has been moved to a background thread and had it's thread priority dropped for Beta 2.
- Close text editor windows you aren't using, and restart Visual Studio periodically (I do about once/day on purpose and 2-10 times/day from crashes - my project is a far edge case that breaks it often).

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about VS2010 but VS 2005 would have that problem I beleive when C++ was being used. To fix it I had to stop intellisence from running by renaming Feacp.dll .